# AWS glue job ERROR: column "id" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I need your help with AWS glue job ERROR: column "id" does not exist
The main goal is to transform data from one RDS(postgresql) to another RDS(postgresql).
I created connections to RDSs. Create Crawlers. Everything works correct.
After that I created a Spark 2.4, Python 3 (Glue Version 1.0) job and try to move modified data from source to target.
But I get an error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException ERROR: column "id" does not exist
```

In source database I have lower case columns name. But I try solution from this article - fails.
I try manualy change from lower case to upper case colums name in script - fails.
When I create a test tables with lower case columns in source and target everything works correctr.

Any ideas how I can resolve this issue.

Best regards.

Comment: artical it means this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58093109/aws-glue-spark-job-fails-to-support-upper-case-column-name-with-double-quotes

Comment: found that this happens when we deal with Id column name in Upper case and this column is primary key. In other cases no errors.

Comment: I have the same issue. Do you know how to solve the issue?